# Get path of the Firebase reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get the Firebase path (location string without the hostname part such as `"users/user1"`) given the Firebase reference? I can't find in the docs and tried to search but no luck.

Now I did like this in Node.js, given Firebase reference `ref`:

```
var url = require('url'); // standard Node.js 'url' module.
var location = url.parse(ref.toString()).pathname;
```

Is this the correct way to do or there exist a more reliable way?

PS. I saw `ref.path.o` is the array containing the strings that can construct the path but I think it's not on the public API and may subject to change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you think of this outside of the context of Firebase, it becomes "How do I get just the path from a URL?" Searching for that is bound to give good results. They'll likely be similar to what you came up with now.

Another approach might be to depend on [Firebase 2.x SDK's `root()` method, which later became the `root` property in Firebase 3 SDK onwards](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/root.html) to determine the base URL.

```
// For Firebase 2.x SDK
var location = ref.toString().substring(ref.root().toString().length);

// For Firebase 3 SDK and later
var location = ref.toString().substring(ref.root.toString().length);
```

Comment: Okay. So it doesn't have the API to call then I guess? (I was expecting that). Thank you for fast reply anyway :)

Comment: I missed something. My original question is how to get the path after the base URL, not the base URL itself (sorry for ambiguity). So the answer would be `var location = ref.toString().substring(ref.root().toString().length);`

Comment: Ah right, I indeed took the wrong part of the string. Fixed now.

Comment: Check the correct location => ref.toString().substring(ref.root.toString().length)

Comment: @JuanDavid the above answer is for the Firebase 2.x SDK (since that was the most recent version that existed when I wrote it). In the Firebase 3.x SDKs, `root` is indeed a read-only property, instead of a function call.