# How to create a firebase path that includes a = sign (without conversion to %3D)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase database, I'm trying to create the following path:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(encodedMail);
```

The `encodedMail` value is: `dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q=` (it's the mail adress test@test.test encoded as Base64).

In the firebase database, this is created as: `dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q%3D`. How can I make sure that the created reference will be: `dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q=`.

I'm able to create this path manually in the Firebase console without problems, but as soon as I create it using this call to `getReference().child()` the `=` sign is converted to `%3D`?

The relevant code is the following:

```
final Map<String, Object> childCreation = new HashMap<>();

Log.d( TAG, "Encoded mail: " + encodedMail );

final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sharedEvents").child(encodedMail);
Log.d( TAG, "Reference: " + ref );

//see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161508/get-path-of-the-firebase-reference
String path = ref.toString().substring(ref.getRoot().toString().length());
Log.d( TAG, "Path: " + path );

childCreation.put( path, "a value");
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(childCreation);
```

Log output:

```
MainActivity: Remove manager: dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q=
MainActivity: Encoded mail: dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q=
MainActivity: Reference: https://xxxxx-development.firebaseio.com/sharedEvents/dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q%3D
MainActivity: Path: /sharedEvents/dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q%3D
```

Comment: As far as I know Firebase doesn't encode child names. The literal string is sent to the server and (if valid/legal) stored there. For example: here is your path in a database of mine: `https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/39931981/dGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3Q=.json`. Can you show how you write to a location and how you then subsequently have a problem?

Comment: Hi Frank, I've extended the question with the relevant code. I guess that I should solve this by refactoring the code (skip the getReference().child() part and directly construct the path as a string).

Comment: Interesting: in Java it indeed prints an encoded URL. I'm not sure where that comes from. Hold on, I'll ask around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `DatabaseReference.toString()` it outputs a URL that can be pasted into a browser. That's the reason the `=` is encoded.

When you [reconstruct a `DatabaseReference` from the string with `getReferenceFromUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)) it decodes the `=` again.